# How to override Excel 2010 feature to break calculation on any key press

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a sheet with long running calculation. But if I press any key or select any cell, the calculation stops and does not resume.
I did not face the same problem in Excel 2003.

Comment: If you go to file - options - formulas, up top are "calculation options". What are those set to?

Comment: I know you can do this via VBA with `Application.Interactive = False` which prevents any input from the keyboard or mouse until the property is set back to `true`. Not sure how to get it to be triggered with a formula. Are you familiar with VBA?

Comment: I am doing this through C#. I have created an excel addin and I load that in excel. But if I press any key, the calculation stops. This happens specifically in excel 2010 only

Answer (score 1):

on the "Formulas"-Tab you might want to switch the calculation options from "automatic" to "manual". You then are able to start the calculation any time you want by pressing "calculate now" but avoid the constant recalculation.

Comment: Please don't use signatures. The site automatically adds one for you. Thanks.